# SqLite to Mysql and PHP without Json.

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I trying to post data from android SQLite database to MySQL database. I come cross many reference. My question is can I post data from Android SQLite database to MySQL database without Json? Json seem very complicated since I don't have a any Json knowledge.So far I can store data in SQLite. I need to post all my data to MySQL. Thank You.

Comment: Json is an easy format to understand. It wouldn't take much time to learn it and I encourage you to do that. 

But if don't want the easy way, there are also many ways around like building model obj and try to manage it.

Comment: Yes you can.
You can send data as string. Basically the josn data is also sent/received as string. But Json is used for formatting the data so that you can easily parse in both ends(server/client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good question.let maximum people get benefit out of this. When you are using a mobile either it could android,IOS,windows no matter what ,the device has to interact with the server in order to exchange the data stored in the server.If you want to browse you need an active internet connection. can you browse without internet on a mobile?? i don't think that technology exist. Similarly, there are only two ways how you can interact with server from mobile devices.

- XML
- JSON

Typically these act as a bridge between two canals.

**XML:**

The data can be transferred from mobile to server and from server to mobile using XML.This is the traditional one.May be first evolved technology.But it is heavy weighted.

**JSON**

This is the advanced technology. Very Light-weighted,quick and easy to learn.Easy to parse. JSON is the common framework that is being used now-a-days.

And when it comes to your question:

you cannot cross canals without a bridge or a boat. which is JSON or XML in your case.